# Prevent database commit on assert failure in php

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, transactions, assert

For the sanity testing of my code I am putting asserts at various places in my code.

I want it to be the case that whenever an assert is hit, the database transaction should not be completed (i.e. the data should not be committed to database, instead it should be rolled back).

I could not find any clean way of achieving this.

I am using the code igniter framework.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: That's not what assert() is for. Just check for errors normally and rollback if you see one.

Comment: a db which auto-commits transactions on disconnect shouldn't ever be used. normal DB behavior is to auto-rollback if a connection/transaction is abandoned.

Comment: @John - Yes, Agree. You are right. Functionality should not be dependent on assert. Ideally asserts will be disabled in production and hence preventing any such roll backs on error. So we should check for errors explicitly and roll back if error occurs.

Comment: @Marc - I am using mySql with codeigniter transaction support, it support auto-rollback on transaction abandoned. But for that it need to be informed. I was trying to inform code igniter to abandon a transaction if an assert is hit.

Comment: then don't use persistent DB connections. mysql will clean up when a connection is closed, including rolling back any open transactions. but if you use persistent conns, then mysql will never see that the other side has gone away, and any subsequent script taking over that connection will end up in a world of hurt when it starts using this "garbage-filled" connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality should not be part of an assert. If it is the case then the functionality will be distorted in production mode when asserts are disabled.

We can perform additional database operation on assert failure to record and track more details of the error, but should not abort/interfere with outside transactions.

Assertions should be used as a debugging feature only. You may use them for sanity-checks that test for conditions that should always be TRUE and that indicate some programming errors if not or to check for the presence of certain features like extension functions or certain system limits and features.

Assertions should not be used for normal runtime operations like input parameter checks. As a rule of thumb your code should always be able to work correctly if assertion checking is not activated.

[More details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.assert.php)